# parse huge csv for using as key and value

Tags: java, android, csv

i have to parse a huge csv which contains 3 values per line.
At first i get the csv of the assets folder and read it line by line.

```
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] string = line.split(",");
            ...
    }
```

Now i want to read the values effectually, to use them later.
I need the first to values as a pair. Each pair pertains the last value in the same line.
for example :

```
    1,2,3
    4,5,6
    ...
```

results:

```
    pair = [1,2];
    pairValue = 3;
    ...
```

but i need all values of the .csv to work with them later as pair and as single (for calculation) so which method is the best to work with this data?

Maybe an `<ArrayList>` or a `HashMap` like

```
     Map <String,String> map =  new HashMap<String,String>();
    //add items 
     map.put(pair,value);
    //get items 
    String valueOfKeys =(String) map.get(pair);
```

I hope one of you understand me and can help.

Comment: How HUGE is your csv?

Comment: there's this thing in computers called database. Android have SQLite

Comment: the data size is 221.048  bytes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first question is will all your data fit in memory? Assuming that it does then you need to decide how you want to be able to look up the data:

1. do you need to access the values based on the row number, eg give me the pair and pairValue for row 1985?
2. do you need to access a pair based on the pairValue, eg give me the pair for pairValue = 3?
3. do you need to iterate through all the data from start to finish?

In the first case an array list would be quickest but be aware that this would involve allocating a large contiguous chunk of memory.

In the second case a hashmap would work, as you've already suggested.

In the third case, a LinkedList would work and would mean that you wouldn't have to allocate a contiguous chunk of memory, but accessing the nth element would be slower.

If the file is too large to fit into memory then you're going to have to write the data to a database table and query it from there.